# Vagrant: avoid requiring 'configure_networks' capability on guest OS, using Tiny Core Linux

Tags: vagrant, tiny-core-linux

I have been working with getting Vagrant to allow me to setup a Tiny Core Linux image, and have been unable to get past the following error:

```
Vagrant attempted to execute the capability 'configure_networks'
on the detect guest OS 'linux', but the guest doesn't
support that capability. This capability is required for your
configuration of Vagrant. Please either reconfigure Vagrant to 
avoid this capability or fix the issue by creating the capability.
```

I have tried playing with the configuration options at http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/basic_usage.html and have so far been unable to find a configuration of config.vm.networks which avoids calling the configure_networks block in Vagrant. Am I missing an obvious configuration or is this a bug in Vagrant?